# Updating multiple records with repeat region in php

Tags: php, mysql

how can i update multiple records in php mysql with repeated region by a textbox?

User should enter the grades of his students and if he clicks the submit button the grades are updated in the database.

this is the code:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
        foreach($_POST['StudentNo'] as $name => $value){
            $MidGrade = $_POST['MidGrade'];
            mysql_query("UPDATE grades SET MidGrade = '$MidGrade' WHERE StudentNo = '$value'")or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
?>

<form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="array.php">
  <table width="500" height="30" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="71">StudentNo</td>
    <td width="500"><div align="center">Student Name </div></td>
    <td width="127">MidGrade</td>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div align="center">
          <input name="StudentNo" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_studentdetails['StudentNo']; ?>" size="10" />
          <?php echo $row_studentdetails['StudentNo']; ?>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div align="left">
          <?php echo $row_studentdetails['LastName']; ?> 
          <?php echo $row_studentdetails['FirstName']; ?> 
          <?php echo $row_studentdetails['MiddleName']; ?>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div align="center">
          <input type="text" name="MidGrade" value="" size="10" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <?php } while ($row_studentdetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($studentdetails)); ?>
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp; </p>
  <p align="center">
    <input name="enter" type="submit" value="Insert record" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: It doesnt update in the database. MidGrade should be updated in the database with its matching StudentNo. @Mihai

Answer (score 0):

Using the IN () function in MySQL, you can update multiple rows. It takes a commaseperated value, like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
$MidGrade = $_POST['MidGrade'];
$values = implode(",", $_POST['StudentNo'])
mysql_query("UPDATE grades SET MidGrade = '$MidGrade' WHERE StudentNo IN ($values)") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

If you're doing what I think you are.

This may not fix your code, but it answers your question.